# Here API: Matrix Routing API V8 - Asynchronus request - Receiving error when retrieving calculation status

Tags: here-api

I'm currently developing a little algorithm to solve the VRP. I herefore use the HERE Matrix Routing API to identify the actual travel times. I just came across the issue, that the retrieved status url after submitting the matrix seems to not accept the API key authorization. Here a little exapmle:

After submitting my matrix, I try to access the status of my calculation via the status url as described in the documentation:

```
https://matrix.router.hereapi.com/v8/matrix/{matrixId}/status?apiKey={apiKey}
```

as well as with the returned status url after submitting the request (which is basically the above URL prefilled and with resolved forwarding):

```
https://aws-eu-west-1.matrix.router.hereapi.com/v8/matrix/{matrixId}/status?apiKey={apiKey}
```

From my understanding and the way how it's documented, I expect this to be working. Instead, I'm receiving an error code **401, Unauthorized: No credentials found**

My request succeeds, when I'm **deleting the /status** after the matrixId. Is this the expected behaviour or did I reveal a little bug?

Thanks for your help!
BR, Difreg

Answer (score 1):

This is unfortunately due to a combination of how the service operates, and how some client libraries are configured to automatically follow [HTTP redirects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections), like Python `requests`.

I answered a similar question a few days ago, and [you can see the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65602683/unable-to-authenticate-asynchronous-requests-on-matrix-routing-v8-heremaps-api/65666174#65666174).

Hopefully that helps you figure it out, but if it doesn't, feel free to ask again here.